# How do i populate a dataframe with the results of a function that searches other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to construct a dataframe that is populated by the results of a series of search functions across a number of data frames, and i don't know where to start - i'm new to python.

The results table i'm constructing is a matrix, with each indexed row referencing a data frame, and each column representing a list. The desired Data frame looks like:

```
answer_df
            List 1                List 2             List 3
       
P1            ?                     ?                   ?
P2            ?                     ?                   ?
P3            ?                     ?                   ?
P4            ?                     ?                   ?
P5            ?                     ?                   ?
P6            ?                     ?                   ?
```

The values need to come from the results of an "is in" search function, where P1 is searched with the contents of each list.

Example dataframe:

```
P1

Index     Diagnosis      Meds     Tests      Obs
0             A12         NAN       NAN      NAN
1             B15         NAN       NAN      NAN
2             C28         NAN       NAN      NAN
3             NAN         D22       NAN      NAN
4             NAN         E91       NAN      NAN
5             NAN         NAN       F14      NAN
6             NAN         NAN       NAN      M55

P2

Index     Diagnosis      Meds     Tests      Obs
0             K11         NAN       NAN      NAN
1             L01         NAN       NAN      NAN
2             C28         NAN       NAN      NAN
3             NAN         X94       NAN      NAN
4             NAN         E91       NAN      NAN
5             NAN         NAN       F14      NAN
6             NAN         NAN       Y02      NAN
```

A list example is:

```
List 1

A12  
L01
D22
K88
F14
M55
N67

List 2
A12
F14
N64
P01
Y02
M55
```

I want to populate the `answer_df` by counting the number of matches between `P1` / `P2' and` List 1' / `List 2` so that it looks like this:

```
answer_df
            List 1                List 2             List 3
       
P1            4                     3                   ?
P2            2                     1                   ?
P3            ?                     ?                   ?
P4            ?                     ?                   ?
P5            ?                     ?                   ?
P6            ?                     ?                   ?
```

But i also need to repeat this function for all other lists and dataframes (3*6 = 18 searches in total). Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` and `isin` to count the number of matches (intersection):

```
# Setup 2 dict for dataframes and lists
P = {'P1': p1, 'P2': p2}
L = {'List 1': l1, 'List 2': l2}

data = {}
for pname, p in P.items():
    for lname, l in L.items():
        count = p.melt().dropna()['value'].isin(l).sum()
        print(f"{pname} - {lname} = {count}")
        data[(pname, lname)] = count

df = pd.Series(data).unstack()
```

**Output**

```
>>> df
    List 1  List 2
P1       4       3
P2       2       2
```

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

data1 = {'Diagnosis': ['A12', 'B15', 'C28', nan, nan, nan, nan],
         'Meds': [nan, nan, nan, 'D22', 'E91', nan, nan],
         'Tests': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'F14', nan],
         'Obs': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'M55']}

p1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Diagnosis': ['K11', 'L01', 'C28', nan, nan, nan, nan],
         'Meds': [nan, nan, nan, 'X94', 'E91', nan, nan],
         'Tests': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'F14', 'Y02'],
         'Obs': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}

p2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

l1 = ['A12', 'L01', 'D22', 'K88', 'F14', 'M55', 'N67']
l2 = ['A12', 'F14', 'N64', 'P01', 'Y02', 'M55']
```